# Gnuplot is connecting every single point together

Tags: gnuplot

I am plotting data in gnuplot like so:

```
set terminal pdf
set output "Planck.pdf"
plot "CalculatedValues.dat" u 1:2 t "Dawn" pt 1 ps .1 with lines
```

But my output ends up looking like a yarn sculpture,

[image]

I want the output to look like, but a line graph instead of a scatter plot.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Here is some data:

```
13.4904 3.13714e+07     3.91106e+07
11.3872 4.64475e+07     5.96647e+07
18.0928 1.40999e+07     1.69117e+07
13.3284 3.23223e+07     4.03737e+07
1.3264  3309.46 24012.2
0.323113        5.16869e-25     1.764e-21
10.6252 5.35423e+07     6.97629e+07
```

It's tab separated and new line separated

Comment: What does your data file look like?  Gnuplot will connect consecutive points together with the lines style.  If your data is in sorted order by the first column, you will get the result that you want.  I suspect that your data is in somewhat random order, which will result in what you are seeing.

Comment: Added to original comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with the order of your points.  Gnuplot will connect consecutive points in the file with lines.  If the points are in order based on the x-axis value (the first column in this case), you will get what you are after.  If they are not, you will get strange results like you are seeing.

### Unsorted Data

```
13.4904   3.13714e+07   3.91106e+07
11.3872   4.64475e+07   5.96647e+07
18.0928   1.40999e+07   1.69117e+07
13.3284   3.23223e+07   4.03737e+07
1.3264    3309.46       24012.2
0.323113  5.16869e-25   1.764e-21
10.6252   5.35423e+07   6.97629e+07
```

`plot datafile u 1:2 w linespoints pt 7` produces the following<sup>**†**</sup>

[image]

Here the points are numbered to show the order they are plotted in.  We can see that points that occur consecutively in the datafile are connected.

### Sorted Data

```
0.323113   5.16869e-25   1.764e-21
1.3264     3309.46       24012.2
10.6252    5.35423e+07   6.97629e+07
11.3872    4.64475e+07   5.96647e+07
13.3284    3.23223e+07   4.03737e+07
13.4904    3.13714e+07   3.91106e+07
18.0928    1.40999e+07   1.69117e+07
```

`plot datafile u 1:2 w linespoints pt 7` produces the following<sup>**†**</sup>

[image]

Here we see that the same points are plotted, but in a different order.  Again, consecutive points are connected, but are done in an increasing order, as the data is sorted in such a matter.

---

The solution is to sort your data first.  Either have the program generating the data sort it during production, or use an external program to sort it before plotting.

If the values in the first column are unique, one of the smoothing options can be used with the original unsorted data.  For example,

```
plot datafile u 1:2 smooth unique w linespoints pt 7
```

will produce the same results as plotting with the sorted data.<sup>**‡**</sup>  This is because the smooth unique option first sorts the data by the x column.  The y values are replaced with the average of all y values with the corresponding x value.  If the x values are unique, this means that the original data is preserved, just in sorted order.

---

<sup>**†**</sup> The plot command shown will only draw the lines.  To get the numerical labels as well, we use

```
plot datafile u 1:2 w linespoints pt 7, \
           "" u 1:2:(sprintf("%d",$0+1)) w labels offset 0,graph 0.05
```

which plots a label at each point coordinate moved upward by 5% of the graph range (using the graph coordinate system).  As the 0 pseudocolumn (the line number) is 0-based, we add one in order to generate the label, which we will give 1-based labels.

<sup>**‡**</sup> If we wanted to label the points here, we would have to use set table to capture the smoothed data, and then plot data.  Doing

```
set table "tempfile"
plot datafile u 1:2 smooth unique
unset table
plot "tempfile" u 1:2 w linespoints pt 7, \
             "" u 1:2:(sprintf("%d",$0+1)) w labels offset 0,graph 0.05
```

will produce exactly the sorted graph above.  The data is captured to a temporary file and the first plot command just generates the points.  The following plot command plots the now sorted data along with the labels.  This allows gnuplot to do all of the sorting itself, but again, this will only work if the values in the first column are unique.

Comment: This is totally it. I just remembered my x values come from my random number generator. Thanks so much, can't believe I missed that